# How to know the status of progress of fs's copy and rename in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, copy, rename, percentage, progress

I am not talking about upload and download.

I want to know the status of progress in a driver and between drivers.

For example, copying file with fs.copy needs time to be done, but there is no way how much the work is done. Furthermore, Renaming between different hard disks also needs time to be finished. However, there are no way to know the progress percentage or size.

Does anybody know how to get the information during copy or rename?

Comment: The built-in functions like [`fs.copyFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisescopyfilesrc-dest-mode) do not provide progress.  You only know when it starts and when it completes.  If you wanted progress, you would have to either develop your own or find a third party solution that provides progress.  It's unclear what you're talking about renaming between different hard disks.   Since the OS does not directly support that, that would essentially be a copy and then delete.

Comment: Renaming means moving files to the different disk. It is rename in fs.